# Find string in js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to find in chrome dev tools debug which object contains a string as a field, in other words, I know I have have a string "abc", but I want to know how the field is named and in what object it is in?

Comment: Right click the text "abc" on the page and click inspect element in the context menu.

Comment: _"and in what object it is in?"_ Can include example of object or array objects at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.grep()` , `Object.keys()`

```js
var obj = [{0:"abc"},{1:"def"}, {2:"ghi"}];

var str = "abc";

var res = $.grep(obj, function(val, key) {
  return val[Object.keys(val)] === str
});
// `res` : object in array of objects `obj`,
// `Object.keys(res)[0]` : name of property within `res`
// which contains `str` : `"abc"`
console.log(res, Object.keys(res)[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```